# VSCode: how to set shell/args for automatically detected npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to start NPM scripts from VSCode with a custom shell (I want the NPM command to be directly prefixed by `wsl.exe --`, e.g. `wsl.exe -- npm start`). I've found a way to make it work but it requires me to set my task type to "shell" and set my shell config like so:

```json
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "options": {
    "shell": { <-- Shell config that I need
      "executable": "wsl.exe",
      "args": [
        "--"
      ]
    },
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell", <-- Sample task I want to execute
      "command": "npm start",
      "label": "...",
      "detail": "...",
    },
```

But VSCode automatic tasks detection ("NPM Scripts" section of the sidebar) uses tasks with the type set as "npm" instead of "shell". This is the config VSCode uses for such automatic tasks:

```json
    {
      "type": "npm", <-- NPM task that I want, but for which the shell config won't apply
      "script": "start",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "npm: start",
      "detail": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
    }
```

And this type of tasks do not use the shell config from the first example above (it uses `wsl.exe -e <npm command>` instead, which can't work in my environment) Is there a way to set a terminal/shell config for this specific kind of tasks?

To reformulate: can I set a shell executable and args for tasks of type "npm" (if so, how?) or I am forced to use tasks of type "shell" and give up on using VSCode automatic tasks detection (which are of the "npm" type)?